# Error during creating my own pod with ObjectiveC

Tags: ios, objective-c, git, cocoapods

I'm creating pod by this great tutorial.
https://www.raywenderlich.com/99386/create-cocoapod-swift.

I use Objective C instead of Swift.
Error happened on this step:

```
pod repo push MyProj MyProj.podspec --verbose
```

Output:

```
Validating spec
    MyProj (0.1.0) - Analyzing on iOS 9.0 platform.
  Preparing

Cloning spec repo `******` from `https://github.com/******/PodSpecs.git`
  $ /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/git clone https://github.com/******/PodSpecs.git ******
  Cloning into '******'...
  warning: You appear to have cloned an empty repository.
 -> MyProj (0.1.0)
    - ERROR | [iOS] unknown: Encountered an unknown error (Unable to create a source with URL https://github.com/******/PodSpecs.git
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/lib/cocoapods/sources_manager.rb:42:in `find_or_create_source_with_url'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:654:in `block in sources'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:653:in `map'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:653:in `sources'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:144:in `resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/lib/cocoapods/validator.rb:373:in `block in download_pod'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/lib/cocoapods/validator.rb:373:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/lib/cocoapods/validator.rb:373:in `download_pod'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/lib/cocoapods/validator.rb:269:in `block in perform_extensive_analysis'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/lib/cocoapods/validator.rb:263:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/lib/cocoapods/validator.rb:263:in `perform_extensive_analysis'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/lib/cocoapods/validator.rb:81:in `validate'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/lib/cocoapods/command/repo/push.rb:125:in `block in validate_podspec_files'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/lib/cocoapods/command/repo/push.rb:119:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/lib/cocoapods/command/repo/push.rb:119:in `validate_podspec_files'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/lib/cocoapods/command/repo/push.rb:64:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/claide-1.0.0/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:50:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/bin/pod:55:in `'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `'
) during validation.

[!] The `MyProj.podspec` specification does not validate.

/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/lib/cocoapods/command/repo/push.rb:130:in `block in validate_podspec_files'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/lib/cocoapods/command/repo/push.rb:119:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/lib/cocoapods/command/repo/push.rb:119:in `validate_podspec_files'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/lib/cocoapods/command/repo/push.rb:64:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/claide-1.0.0/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:50:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/bin/pod:55:in `'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `'
```

My podspec file:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|

s.platform = :ios

s.ios.deployment_target = '9.0'

s.name = "MyProj"

s.summary = "MyProj lets a user create his own timer."

s.requires_arc = true

s.version = "0.1.0"

s.license = { :type => "MIT", :file => "LICENSE" }

s.author = { "*** ***" => "***@***.com" }

s.homepage = "https://github.com/******/MyProj"

s.source = { :git => "https://github.com/******/MyProj.git", :tag => "#{s.version}"}

s.framework = "UIKit"

s.dependency 'ReactiveCocoa', '~> 2.5.0'

s.source_files = "MyProj/**/*.{h,m}"

s.resources = "MyProj/**/*.{png,jpeg,jpg,storyboard,xib}"

end
```

I did all previous steps in tutorial.

Using latest version of cocoapods.

How can I fix this error?

I will be grateful for any help!

Comment: can you also tell, if you have added tag to your source repo against which you are trying to clone in pod? Also, have you added your PodSpec repo to pod?

Comment: @prabodhprakash, I added tag, and pod spec repository too.

Comment: Instead of pod repo push, can you try doing pod spec lint <pod spec name> --verbose and paste the output here, if it is the same?

Comment: @prabodhprakash, I got this error after command
pod spec lint Myproj.podspec
"Myproj (0.1.0)
    - ERROR | [iOS] unknown: Encountered an unknown error (Unable to find a specification for `ReactiveCocoa (~> 2.5.0)` depended upon by `Myproj`." It's better then unknown error!

Comment: do this ReactiveCocoa (~> 2.5) i.e. remove that last 0 @Hot'n'Young

Comment: @prabodhprakash, I got the same error
- ERROR | [iOS] unknown: Encountered an unknown error (Unable to find a specification for `ReactiveCocoa (~> 2.5)` depended upon by `Myproj`) during validation.

Comment: the syntax looks incorrect - try this:  `pod 'ReactiveCocoa', '~> 2.5'` or if this does not work, just write pod`'ReactiveCocoa'` @Hot'n'Young

Comment: @prabodhprakash, I wrote 'ReactiveCocoa', but got that error. Syntax in *.podsec file is correct.
- ERROR | [iOS] unknown: Encountered an unknown error (Unable to find a specification for `ReactiveCocoa` depended upon by `Myproj`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124886/discussion-between-prabodhprakash-and-hotnyoung).